# Is there a default variable placeholder for lambdas in java8?

Tags: lambda, java-8

Is there a default variable placeholder for lambdas in java8, like `_` for scala?

Here is scala example:

```
case class Person(name:String, age:Int)
val people = List(Person("Jack", 35), Person("Arjun", 16), Person("Sasha", 13), Person("Sara", 8))
val teens = people.filter(_.age >= 13).filter(_.age <= 19)
```

Assuming there is a Person class defined, here is java example:

```
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(new Person("Jack", 35), new Person("Arjun", 16), new Person("Sasha", 13), new Person("Sara", 8));
List<Person> teens = people.stream()
                           .filter(p -> (p.getAge() >= 13 && p.getAge() <= 19))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a way to write the filter in last line without defining variable `p`. Obviously this is not a big issue, but just curious. I also understand that I could write a method in Person class like `isTeenager` and pass that to lambda, but that's not the point either. Just want to know if there is a default variable placeholder for lambdas in java8.

Comment: I don't think so. It's not supported for the moment (and I don't know if it will be in the future).

Comment: In the other hand the JLS states _"The use of the variable name _ in any context is discouraged. Future versions of the Java programming language may reserve this name as a keyword and/or give it special semantics."_ So the developers try to preserve this character. I'm a bit lazy to search on mailing lists, maybe this topic has already been discussed.

Comment: See also http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-August/010673.html.  Brian Goetz states _"Your suspicion is mostly right, except that we are certainly NOT going to do Scala's "wunderbar".  However, things it might be used for include things like "I don't want to give this variable a name" (such as catch parameters that are never used.)"_ So likely to be not supported :-)

Comment: In Java 8, using _ as an identifier was deprecated, and in Java 9, it has been made illegal, leaving room for it to mean something more useful in Java 10+.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's been [proposed and rejected](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-September/004027.html):

> wunderbars were considered and (overwhelmingly) rejected by the EG.

Comment: I read that entire thread looking for justification.  I guess the word "overwhelmingly" is it?

Answer (score 9):

There isn't, no. You could use a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to make it a bit closer; for that you would define a boolean method `isATeen(Person p)` and then do something like this:

```
List<Person> teens = people.stream()
                       .filter(Person::isATeen)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Assuming that you defined the method is defined in Person. You could define it elsewhere.)

That way you don't have to explicitly create a name for the instance of `Person` in the filter. You do of course do so in the method, so it's not much better.

**UPDATE:** With [JEP 302, Phase 2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/302) in JDK 9 the underscore has actually become an illegal name for a variable in any position. That way, future Java versions may use `_` as a default placeholder for lambdas in a similar way to languages such as Scala. Or they may use it differently or not at all. We'll have to wait an see.